# SQL function similar to xmlagg or listagg

Tags: sql, oracle

Am new to SQl and I have written a query to pull event reports from event database, where in the data of each event is stored in different tables based on the event slot information.
Below are the tables:

```
EVENT_D

ID     HOST       MESSAGE 
---------- ----------------- 
ID1    server1    Server Down
ID2    server2    File System Issue

EVENT_INFO

ID    RECEIVED_TIME          
---------- -------------
ID1   03-05-2019 12:09PM
ID2   03-06-2019 03:00AM

EVENT_OPERATIONS

ID     EG_TIME               EG_OPERATION 
---------- ------------------------------- 
ID1    03-05-2019 12:10 PM    Blacked Out
ID1    03-05-2019 12:10 PM    Reopened
ID1    03-05-2019 12:13 PM    Ownership Taken
ID1    03-05-2019 12:50 PM    Closed
ID2    03-06-2019 03:05 AM    Rule applied
ID2    03-06-2019 03:06 AM    Ownership Taken
ID2    03-06-2019 03:07 AM    Ticket triggered
ID2    03-06-2019 03:30 AM    Closed
```

**Expected Output:**

```
ID     HOST       MESSAGE               RECEIVED_TIME           Operations
---------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
ID1    server1    Server Down           03-05-2019 12:09PM      Blacked Out 03-05-2019 12:10 PM; Reopened 03-05-2019 12:10 PM; Ownership Taken 03-05-2019 12:13 PM; Closed 03-05-2019 12:50 PM
ID2    server2    File System Issue     03-06-2019 03:00AM      Rule applied 03-06-2019 03:05 AM; Ownership Taken 03-06-2019 03:06 AM; Ticket triggered 03-06-2019 03:07 AM; Closed 03-06-2019 03:30 AM
```

**Query Used:**

```
  SELECT a.ID          AS Event_ID,
         a.HOST        AS Hostname,
         a.MESSAGE     AS EventMessage,
         b.RECEIVED_TIME AS EventReception,
         LISTAGG (
             c.EG_OPERATION || TO_CHAR (c.EG_TIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh12:mi:ss AM'),
             ';')
         WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c.EG_TIME) as Operations
    FROM EVENT_D a
         INNER JOIN EVENT_INFO b ON b.ID = a.ID
         INNER JOIN EVENT_OPERATIONS c ON c.ID = a.ID
   WHERE     b.RECEIVED_TIME >= TO_DATE ('2019-03-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss')
         AND b.RECEIVED_TIME < TO_DATE ('2019-03-04', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss')
GROUP BY a.ID,
         a.HOST,
         a.MESSAGE,
         b.RECEIVED_TIME
```

> **Problem:**
>
> If the query is executed without **listagg/xmlagg** function and **groupby**
>   expression the number of records in the output will be around 6000 per
>   day(in real case scenario). But due to usage of **groupby** expression in
>   the above query there is the a miss match in the event count. Events
>   are getting grouped by host, message and other slots which is in turn
>   affecting the count. Instead of 6000 records we are getting around 600 >records in real case scenario.

**Question:** Is there any other function apart from listagg/xmlagg which can provide us the output in the expected format.

Comment: Of course you get fewer records with the `GROUP BY`.  The query combines multiple rows into one.  That is *why* you use `GROUP BY` and `LISTAGG()`.

Comment: Sorry, what's the issue? What do you mean there is a miss-match in the event count? Do you think that the listagg function is removing duplicates?

Comment: @JoshEller Yes, since its grouping based on the ID, SERVER, HOST and RECEIVED_TIME am getting lesser number of records in the final report. I want record for each event, I don't want it to remove duplicates or to get grouped.

Comment: @GordonLinoff , How can this be avoided, is there any other way to get the expected output without using LISTAGG() function.

Comment: The listagg function does not remove duplicates in itself. I would start by looking at your query without the grouping, and see if it's returning the results you'd expect.

Comment: If I execute it without grouping it gives below error.
[Error]ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want `LISTAGG()` as a window function:

```
SELECT . . .,
       LISTAGG (c.EG_OPERATION || TO_CHAR (c.EG_TIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh12:mi:ss AM'),
                ';'
               ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c.EG_TIME) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, HOST) as Operations
```

You would then remove the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Suppose If there are two more columns in `SELECT` clause do I have to include that also in `PARTITION BY`  ???

Comment: @NischithaM . . . The `partition by` column define the grouping for the `listagg()` operator.  Those columns are not directly related to columns in the `select`.

Comment: I tried this method, when I execute the query it just says processing statement but am not getting any output even after waiting for 30 mins.